# How can I get the filesize in OnComponentSavePre?

Tags: event-system, 5.3

I'm using Tridion 5.3, and I'm trying to check the Multimedia filesize in the `OnComponentSavePre` event (using a C# event handler) using `Component.Multimedia.FileSize`

I'm sure that I have done this before, but now I get

> 'Unable to get filesize of Unknown'...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Probably because the file is not yet saved, and therefore Tridion can't determine its size?

You could try something like this instead:

```cs
MemoryStream ImageStream = new MemoryStream(Component.Multimedia.GetBinaryContent());
MMImage = Image.FromStream(ImageStream);
Component.MetadataFields[IMAGE_WIDTH_FIELD].value[1] = MMImage.Size.Width.ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

I wrote this for a 5.3 Event System, not sure it would work on later versions... What I do is I try to load the image from its "Multimedia Filename". This is the path that the image was uploaded from, but given that it might have been uploaded from a client's workstation, the file may not exist on the server. In that case, I try to load the image from the web\upload folder (where the Tridion CME would have copied the image to before saving it in a component).

```
Image image = null;
if(Component.Info.Version < 1) // New Component
{
    string fileName = null;
    string uploadFolder = null;
    if(!File.Exists(Component.Multimedia.Filename))
    {
        uploadFolder = GetTridionInstallPath() + @"web\Upload\"; //Dragons be here
        fileName = uploadFolder + Path.GetFileName(Component.Multimedia.Filename);
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = Component.Multimedia.Filename;
    }
    if(File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        FileStream imageStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.logEvent("Could not find file " + filename, EnumSeverity.severityInfo);
    }
}
else
{
    MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(Component.Multimedia.GetBinaryContent());
    image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
}
if(image != null)
{
    try
    {
        Component.MetadataFields[IMAGE_WIDTH_FIELD].value[1] = MMImage.Size.Width.ToString();
        Component.MetadataFields[IMAGE_HEIGTH_FIELD].value[1] = MMImage.Size.Height.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.logEvent("Could not get image dimensions, first version? Error: " + ex.ToString(), EnumSeverity.severityError);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't even get the 'BinaryContent' at this point.

Comment: You're right. Let me update my answer.